# jQuery: контроль выбора radiobutton

Tags: jquery

Добрый день! Есть условная форма с двумя радиобаттонами и сабмитом:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" id="one" />
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2" id="two" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Есть не выбрать ни один из вариантов, то отправка формы не состоится:

```
if($('input[name=radio]').attr('checked') != 'checked')) {
  alert('Вы не сделали выбор');
  return false;
}
```

А вот с отправкой формы при выборе того или иного варианта возникли проблемы. Пытался вешать обработчики по клику:

```
$('#one').click(function() {
  $('#one').attr('checked', true);
});

$('#two').click(function() {
  $('#two').attr('checked', true);
});
```

Но отрабатывает только #one, а при выборе #two снова выводит алерт. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `radio` и `checkbox` вообще не меняются аттрибуты при изменении, надо использовать селектор `:checked`:

```
if(!$('input[name=radio]:checked').val()) {
  alert('Вы не сделали выбор');
  return false;
}
```

И соответственно нет необходимости вручную ставить аттрибут по клику. У вас была ошибка что вы ставили `true`, что просто ставило аттрибут `checked` без значения. А проверяли вы его на значение.

Comment: Попробовал так, как Вы предлагаете: всё равно отрабатывает только при выборе #one. А при выборе #two выдает алерт ((

Comment: Извиняюсь, действительно перепутал с чекбоксом, исправил ответ

Comment: Да, так заработало. Спасибо!